# Why domain auto change IP 2/3 times in a day?

Tags: dns

I transfered domain from one server to another around 10 days ago. Now I it change its IP address of old server and new server automatic 2/3 times in a day.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you did not update all your DNS servers when you changed your domain?

Try checking:

```
host example.com nameserver1
host example.com nameserver2
host example.com nameserver3
```

where you use the nameservers listed in `whois example.com` for the nameservers, and you use your domain in place of `example.com` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't delete the old server record in your dns manager.